# What do the ranked match stat icons mean in ONRUSH?

Tags: onrush

When finishing a ranked match and viewing the final results stats, what determines the icon to the far right of each player? Is it the last car played?

Some players also have a little orange bar graph looking icon next to it, orange regardless of which team. What does it signify?

Penultimate player on blue team has the orange bar graph icon
[[image: Penultimate player on blue team has the orange bar graph icon]]

3rd place on orange team has it
[[image: 3rd place on orange team has it]]